# What's the female equivalent of "suitor"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a word which could satisfy the usage of "suitor", except it would be used to indicate female "suitors":

E.g.:

> She had a host of suitors eagerly awaiting her favour...

Now, I want a word that could fit in this sentence, except it would be about females:

> *He* had a bevy of ?????? eagerly awaiting *his* favour...

Comment: You could steal from [Elvis Costello](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Clubland-lyrics-Elvis-Costello/9AA8B09B15AF7294482568AF00234F30), adjust it a little, and call them a *bevy of beauties*.

Comment: Would "supplicant" be even remotely synonymous with "female suitor"?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I don't think there's a close corresponding term. 'Suitress' just sounds made-up and 'female suitor' makes obvious the one-sidedness of the term 'suitor'. I can only suggest an alternative, something like 'prospects'.

Comment: Modern times call for modern measures... Don't let the ender define the word.

Comment: I used the word suitor on my Wikipedia article on The Fortunes of Perkin Warbeck for the prospective brides of James IV, neither of whom he ultimately married (James married Princess Margaret, older sister of Henry VIII, but that isn't covered in the novel, and she appears in only one scene, comforting a dog Henry has abused). I was looking to see if there is a better word, and it doesn't appear that there is one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think one day the word for this will be *suitor*, just as now *actresses* are sometimes simply called *actors*. Until then, it seems that *female suitor* is the most common phrase.

This example is from a *New York Times* book review of [*An Available Man*](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/01/22/books/review/an-available-man-by-hilma-wolitzer-book-review.html):

> He picks it up to hear the clamorous, intrusive voice of **a female suitor**, attempting to break in on his grief. But he’d rather iron the blouses of his deceased wife, Bee, “as a way of reconnecting with her when she was so irrevocably gone” than date any of the women now scurrying in his direction. Bee, on her deathbed, had predicted this fate: “Look at you. They’ll be crawling out of the woodwork.”

Comment: +1: I prefer this to *suitress*, which is obscure and would likely not be understood by the average speaker.

Comment: For the record, I'd opt for "female suitor" over "suitress" as well − but it's still worth knowing both options exist.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say the appropriate word **now** is *suitor*. Certainly that's what I'd use in the OP's example.

Comment: @Martha, except that most dictionary definitions of *suitor* specify a man.

Comment: I like "female suitor". Thanks!. +1

Answer (score 12):

It may be a bit of a dated term, but *[suitress](http://www.wordnik.com/words/suitress)* would be the female equivalent.

(I'm not sure about the collective noun, though.  Instead of "a *host* of suitresses," you might want to use *bevy* instead).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try using "suitress" and see if I can "revive" the term. Or just fall back on "suitor".

Comment: Sounds good to me.  I've never had these problems before – i.e., I've never had a bevy of suitresses vying for my attention, so I never had to figure out what to call them, either.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to give the impression of aggressive females, then the "female suitor" term fits.

I think that "admirer" could work in many situations where you don't want to necessarily indicate aggressiveness.

"He had a bevy of admirers eagerly awaiting his favour."

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this will work out.

Being a 'suitor' is a male prerogative. It's a relic of an era when men were the ones who went out to look for wives and women stayed at home waiting for men to ask for their hand (hands?).

So being technically correct here would not make much sense.

It's somewhat like the word 'temptress'. Traditionally this is the role of a woman. To call a man a 'tempter' just doesn't taste quite the same. That's assuming that you roll the words around on your tongue before saying them.

Answer (score 0):

Still make use of the word *suitors* for women who are about to propose to men (with a ring in her right hand and on her knee). It will still be okay if you use it as part of the vocabulary, trust me.

I have heard of a woman who was a superviser or boss at a school referred to as a *headmaster* once. More so terms like *doctor*, *band* (plural), or *pilot* are used interchangeably for both genders.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the "suitrix" portmanteau (suit with the 'rix' affixed morpheme).  Not as forced as 'suitress,' gives more of an aura of agency, power.

Comment: *Suitrix* does not appear in reputable online dictionaries. (http://onelook.com/?w=suitrix&ls=a) The presumption is always that someone looking for a word is looking for a *known* word, unless they specifically say they want help coining a new word.

Comment: If you're going to use Latin suffixes, why not be consistent and go with "secutrix." Besides the fact that nobody will understand what you're talking about, of course.