# What do you call a lady being proposed to by a man

Tags: single-word-requests

When a man makes advances to a lady and proposes to her, what single noun would you give to the man and also to the woman?

Example:

> Mr.A has proposed to Ms.B. In this context,
>
> Mr.A is a ________ , and Ms.B is a ________ .

Comment: Please provide some context, otherwise the answers may vary wildly between *suitor* and *stalker*, if not even wider.

Comment: @michael.hor.257k -- I have given the answer 'suitor' without seeing your comment which mentions the word.

Comment: Do you mean "propose", as in ask to marry, or "proposition" as in ask to have sex? The two usually, but not always, mean different things.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast in fact the meaning of 'proposal' is usually marriage proposal but the expression 'makes advances' in the question is what supports the possible meaning of 'proposition.' You might remember the famous Hollywood film ['Indecent proposal.'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=+%27Indecent+proposal%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dKBjWdqTCIfj8weM95WwDA) However, interpreting the question thus would lead to entirely different conclusions.

Comment: [Please read this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Comment: Mr. A is a _fool_ and Ms. B is _lucky_.

Comment: @NVZ the entire sample sentence needed to be highlighted in order to convey the meaning. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @EnglishStudent The OP needs to provide the sample sentences because only the OP knows how they want to use the words!

Comment: @curiousdannii I later saw you have read my meta question about inconsistent use of close-reasons. So you might have made out that my objection is not related to the merit or quality of this particular question but to the misuse of close-reasons in general to 'shut down' questions that some close-vote-enabled members dislike. Please give me your valuable feedback in more detail at the meta page.

Comment: @EnglishStudent there's no misuse in closing questions that don't meet the site rules. You're the only one misusing the site with your inappropriate edits.

Answer (score 5):

A man who proposes to a woman is commonly called a **suitor**, though this term may possibly be outdated in modern usage in favor of similar-meaning words like ['beau'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=beau&oq=beau&aqs=chrome..69i57.1355j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) which can, but need not necessarily, connote a *proposal of marriage* as implicit: see synonyms in the 'beau' link.

> Suitor [noun] a man who courts or woos a woman (some dictionaries also say: with a view to marriage., which is the *traditional* meaning.)

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suitor

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suitor

> Example (mine) She is *still* considering the proposal of her long-time ***suitor***? OMG it's been 8 years now...

A related question has been asked here in 2012: [What's the female equivalent of "suitor"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63695/whats-the-female-equivalent-of-suitor) However it is about *a woman who proposes to a man*, which is very different from what you are asking.

There may not be a common word for the *woman being proposed to*, in your question, but a less common word 'proposee' has indeed been suggested by AndyT in the earlier answer.

Comment: Interesting; I would have thought that “beau” was outdated and “suitor” was current.  P.S. AFAIK there is no policy on this, but I would encourage you to link to google.com rather than google.co.in.

Comment: @Scott googling anything from India in Chrome or Firefox browser automatically goes to www.google.in which is apparently the default setting. I can't get around it. I type google.com, it goes to google.in! It's administrative, I think. And so there would seem to be very little if no difference between the search results returned on google.com and google.in -- at least for these purposes: the word 'beau' in modern parlance appears to be a fashionable substitute for 'boyfriend' especially when talking of celebrities.

Answer (score 4):

The man in this case is the **[Proposer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proposer)**:

> Someone who proposes

and the woman is the **[Proposee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proposee)**:

> 1.The person to whom a proposal of marriage is made

<sup>Definitions from wiktionary</sup>

I wouldn't say they were common words, but it's fairly obvious given context what they mean. As commented by @Mitch: they "sound overly formal or even legalistic". Also note that "proposer" doesn't just mean someone who proposes marriage; it is possibly more common in meaning "someone who proposes an idea".

Comment: This may be factually correct but would sound overly formal or even legalistic.

Comment: @Mitch - I completely agree. Thanks for the comment, I have now incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The lady being proposed to by a man is the man's ***love interest***.

Wiktionary:

> *Noun*
>   **[love interest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/love_interest)** (*plural* love interests)
>
> One who is of interest as a potential partner in love

Comment: Congratulations for finding a word that we couldn't think of or locate! +1

Comment: [Please read this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Comment: This seems to refer to a girlfriend or boyfriend, but not necessarily one that you want to marry, and especially not a person that you have proposed to.